# Dual Thunderbolt Monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook-pro, thunderbolt

I have 16.04 (with kernel `4.4.0-15-generic`) running on a MacBook Pro (`MacBookPro12,1`) and two 27-inch Apple Thunderbolt Displays. The MacBook has two thunderbolt ports. The same issue happened in 15.10, so I decided to try a newer kernel, hence moving to 16.04 dev.

If I plug in a single monitor it is recognized and I can use it as a display. It does not matter which of the two monitors or which of the two ports I use in the single monitor case, all combinations work. If I plug in two (either daisy chained or with each monitor plugged into a separate thunderbolt port), both show up via `lsusb` but only one of them can be configured as a display.

The output of `lsusb` with a single monitor:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05ac:9227 Apple, Inc. Thunderbolt Display
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ac:1112 Apple, Inc. FaceTime HD Camera (Display)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:1107 Apple, Inc. Thunderbolt Display Audio
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05ac:9127 Apple, Inc. Hub in Thunderbolt Display
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 05ac:0273 Apple, Inc.
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 05ac:8290 Apple, Inc.
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0461:4d81 Primax Electronics, Ltd Dell N889 Optical Mouse
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The output of `lsusb` with two monitors:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05ac:9227 Apple, Inc. Thunderbolt Display
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05ac:1112 Apple, Inc. FaceTime HD Camera (Display)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05ac:1107 Apple, Inc. Thunderbolt Display Audio
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05ac:9127 Apple, Inc. Hub in Thunderbolt Display
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05ac:9227 Apple, Inc. Thunderbolt Display
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ac:1112 Apple, Inc. FaceTime HD Camera (Display)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:1107 Apple, Inc. Thunderbolt Display Audio
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05ac:9127 Apple, Inc. Hub in Thunderbolt Display
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 005: ID 05ac:0273 Apple, Inc.
Bus 007 Device 004: ID 05ac:8290 Apple, Inc.
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The graphics driver in use (via `lshw -c video`):

```
*-display
    description: VGA compatible controller
    product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 2
    bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
    version: 09
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
    configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
    resources: irq:70 memory:c0000000-c0ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```

Other interesting facts: the USB hub on both monitors works when daisy chained or each plugged in individually, even on the monitor that is not recognized as a display.

Is there a way to get both monitors to work?

Comment: The OP has stated that the same problem occurs in 15.10, 16.04 _and_ 16.04dev. This is therefore on topic.

Comment: I'm curious if you've made in progress on this problem?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I gave up on using two monitors. :-/

Comment: I agree with @terdon the OP used valid version 15.10 initially and only resorted to 16.04 dev version out of desperation. In reality I think the problem lays more in Kernel `4.4.0-15-generic` and subsequent USB C ThunderBolt 3 code revisions repaired the problem. Even as recent as 4.10 there were revisions IIRC.

Comment: @Alex I voted to reopen your question. I think I read the problem was solved around `4.4.0-23-generic` or so. I'll be getting my own USB-C Thunderbolt 3 soon and will do some testing.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I look forward to an answer then! :-D I no longer have access to two thunderbolt monitors, so I can't test anymore.